# How to parse a timespan in order to add it to a datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

I've got a string in the following format: `05/06/2019|1330|60`

The output I'm looking for is: `05/06/2019T14:30:00`

I'm attempting to parse out the `TimeSpan` portion right now:

```
  public static string getProcedureEndingDateTime (string input) {
    //05/06/2019|1330|60

    string myDate = input.Split ( '|' ) [0];
    DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse (myDate);

    string myTime = input.Split('|')[1];
    string hours = myTime.Substring(0,2);
    string minutes = myTime.Substring(2,2);
    TimeSpan myTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse($"{hours}:{minutes}");

    myDateTime.Add(myTimeSpan);

    return myDateTime.ToString();
}
```

But right now, getting the following output:

[image]

To get the above output I'm calling my function like so:

```
Console.WriteLine (getProcedureEndingDateTime("05/06/2019|1330|60"));
```

**How do I parse the string "1330" into a TimeSpan?**

Comment: Please add the actual stack trace, not a partial screenshot of it.

Comment: @0xFF thanks i've updated

Comment: Is the 60 on the end of the input the time zone offset (in minutes)?

Answer (score 3):

No need to us a Timespan here, just call ParseExact instead with a proper format to do it in one line.

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("05/06/2019|1330|60", "dd/MM/yyyy|HHmm|60", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString()); 
//this gives 2019-06-05 1:30:00 PM, format depends on your PC's locale
```

I don't know what the 60 part is, you can adjust the format or substring it out beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because `Add()` returns a new `DateTime` instance, which means you're currently discarding it. Store it, and return that from your function instead, like so:

```
var adjusted = myDateTime.Add(myTimeSpan);
return adjusted.ToString();
```

Comment: so how do i not discard it?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Save the result of `Add()` into a variable, like I've shown in the code above, and return that from your function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the numeric values as exactly that, numbers.

Also, the other issue with your code is the `DateTime.Add()` method doesn't add to that DateTime variable. Instead it returns a new variable, which you are ignoring.

Try this:

```
 public static string getProcedureEndingDateTime (string input) {
    string[] parts = input.Split('|');
    string myDate = parts[0];
    DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse (myDate);

    string myTime = parts[1];
    if (!int.TryParse(myTime.Substring(0,2), out int hours))
        hours = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(myTime.Substring(2,2), out int minutes))
        minutes = 0;
    TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);

    myDateTime += myTimeSpan;

    return myDateTime.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date shown is May 6th (and not June 5th), and also assuming the `60` represents a time zone offset expressed in minutes *west* of GMT, and also assuming you want the corresponding UTC value, then:

```
public static string getProcedureEndingDateTime (string input) {

    // example input: "05/06/2019|1330|60"

    // separate the offset from the rest of the string
    string dateTimeString = input.Substring(0, 15);
    string offsetString = input.Substring(16);

    // parse the DateTime as given, and parse the offset separately, inverting the sign
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "MM/dd/yyyy|HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-int.Parse(offsetString));

    // create a DateTimeOffset from these two components
    DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);

    // Convert to UTC and return a string in the desired format
    DateTime utcDateTime = dto.UtcDateTime;
    return utcDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

A few additional points:

- Not only is the input format strange, but so is your desired output format.  It is strange to see a `T` separating the date and time and also see the date in the `05/06/2019` format.   `T` almost always means to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which requires year-month-day ordering and hyphen separators.  I'd suggest either dropping the `T` if you want a locale-specific format, or keep the `T` and use the standard format.  Don't do both.
- In ISO 8601, it's also a good idea to append a `Z` to UTC-based values.  For `DateTime` values, the [`K` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) should be used for that.  In other words, you probably want the last line above to be:

  ```
  return utcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  // outputs: "2019-05-06T14:30:00Z"
  ```
- You might want to not format a string here, but instead return the `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` value.  It's usually better to create a string only at the time of display.
- Don't forget that the `DateTime` struct is immutable.  In your question you were ignoring the return value of the `Add` method.